# How to link Combo Box elements in Qt with predefined elements in static vector with same index?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I have **20 elements** stored in **vector**, what I want to do is that :
when user selects one **element from drop down list (Combo Box)** the Value of Source or Destination of My Navigation (Routing) **gets the unsigned int value with same index** of element on Combo Box **from the vector**, how can I do That with Combo Box on Qt ?
[image: My GUI Interface]

```
//Start
void MainWindow::fill_MyPlaces(){
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Aldi Store",1545694404)); //1 Aldi
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Restaurant Le Fut",1544558413)); //2 Restaurant Le Fut
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Place Schnider",1455348628)); //3 place schnider
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Acacias Residence",1540689869)); //4 Acacias
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("IUT University",442028765));  //5 IUT
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Train Station (Gare du Creusot)",1387416514)); //6 Train Station (Gare du Creusot)
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Carrefour Shopping Center",1829507841)); //7 Carrefour
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Condorcet Center University",2019043458)); //8 Condorcet
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Hospital Creusot",2258325836)); //9 Hospital Creusot
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("BNP PariBank",1544079469)); //10 BNP PariBank
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Acion Store",889114982)); //11 Action Store
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("El-Loco Cafe",1540689876));//12 El-Loco Cafe
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Residence Jean Monnent",2244694498));//13 Residence Jean Monnent
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Crous Office & Restaurant",1540680545));//14 Crous Office & Restaurant
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Euro Lav(Laundry)",4846313478));//15 Euro Lav(Laundry)
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Pharmacie des Acacias",1540689863));//16 Pharmacie des Acacias
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Centre Medico Scolaire (Medical school)",1544558417));//17 centre medico scolaire (Medical school)
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Driving School",1544558167));//18 Driving School
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("Le Poste",2019027442));//19 Le Poste
    MyPlaces.push_back(make_pair("MCDonld's",6269205284));//20 McDonald's
}
//End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QComboBox allows you to store additional information through the roles that can be accessed through `itemData()`:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr): 
        QWidget(parent), combo(new QComboBox), label(new QLabel)
    {
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout{this};
        lay->addWidget(combo);
        lay->addWidget(label);
        connect(combo, 
            QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), 
            this, 
            &Widget::onCurrentIndexChanged);

        for(const std::pair<QString, int> & p: std::vector<std::pair<QString, int>>{
            {"Aldi Store", 1545694404}, //1 Aldi
            {"Restaurant Le Fut",1544558413}, //2 Restaurant Le Fut
            {"Place Schnider",1455348628}, //3 place schnider
            {"Acacias Residence",1540689869}, //4 Acacias
            {"IUT University",442028765},  //5 IUT
            {"Train Station (Gare du Creusot)",1387416514}, //6 Train Station (Gare du Creusot)
            {"Carrefour Shopping Center",1829507841}, //7 Carrefour
            {"Condorcet Center University",2019043458}, //8 Condorcet
            {"Hospital Creusot",2258325836}, //9 Hospital Creusot
            {"BNP PariBank",1544079469}, //10 BNP PariBank
            {"Acion Store",889114982}, //11 Action Store
            {"El-Loco Cafe",1540689876},//12 El-Loco Cafe
            {"Residence Jean Monnent",2244694498},//13 Residence Jean Monnent
            {"Crous Office & Restaurant",1540680545},//14 Crous Office & Restaurant
            {"Euro Lav(Laundry)",4846313478},//15 Euro Lav(Laundry)
            {"Pharmacie des Acacias",1540689863},//16 Pharmacie des Acacias
            {"Centre Medico Scolaire (Medical school)",1544558417},//17 centre medico scolaire (Medical school)
            {"Driving School",1544558167},//18 Driving School
            {"Le Poste",2019027442},//19 Le Poste
            {"MCDonld's",6269205284},//20 McDonald's
        }){
            combo->addItem(p.first, p.second);
        }
    }
public slots:
    void onCurrentIndexChanged(int index){
        int value = combo->itemData(index).value<int>();
        label->setNum(value);
    }
private:
    QComboBox *combo;
    QLabel *label;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```